# Missing dependencies

Tags: maven-2, gwt, gxt

i get suddenly an error message, that 3 dependencies are missing: gwt-user.jar, gwt-dev.jar and gxt.jar. All jars are in my local repo:

```
dage [~/.m2/repository] $ ls -l com/google/gwt/gwt-user
insgesamt 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 dage Domain Users 4096 2010-01-13 14:55 1.5.3
drwxr-xr-x 2 dage Domain Users 4096 2010-01-13 11:10 1.6.4
drwxr-xr-x 2 dage Domain Users 4096 2010-01-13 16:10 2.0.0
dage [~/.m2/repository] $ ls -l com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/
insgesamt 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 dage Domain Users 4096 2010-01-13 14:55 1.5.3
drwxr-xr-x 3 dage Domain Users 4096 2010-01-13 11:02 1.6.4
drwxr-xr-x 2 dage Domain Users 4096 2010-01-15 09:58 2.0.0
dage [~/.m2/repository] $ ls -l com/extjs/gxt/
insgesamt 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 dage Domain Users 4096 2010-01-14 14:29 2.0.1
drwxr-xr-x 2 dage Domain Users 4096 2010-01-21 12:18 2.1.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 dage Domain Users  288 2010-01-21 12:18 maven-metadata-com.extjs.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 dage Domain Users   40 2010-01-21 12:18 maven-metadata-com.extjs.xml.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 dage Domain Users  323 2010-01-21 12:01 maven-metadata-local.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 dage Domain Users  288 2010-01-21 12:18 maven-metadata.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 dage Domain Users   32 2010-01-21 12:18 maven-metadata.xml.md5
-rw-r--r-- 1 dage Domain Users   40 2010-01-21 12:18 maven-metadata.xml.sha1
```

and the pom entry is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${gwt.home}/gwt-user.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${gwt.home}/gwt-dev.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Needed for ExtGWT -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.extjs</groupId>
        <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
        <version>${gxt.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

<properties>
    <gwt.version>2.0.0</gwt.version>
    <gxt.version>2.1.0</gxt.version>
</properties>
```

I don't have made any maven changes and the pom was also not changed. I've just added and modified java/css/hml files. Any ideas, what is wrong?

edit: Exact message is

```
Missing:
----------
1) com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.0.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.google.gwt -DartifactId=gwt-user -Dversion=2.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.google.gwt -DartifactId=gwt-user -Dversion=2.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
.
.
.
```

and I build the project in command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can't explain it, but after reboot is working again...

Comment: I've had that as well; must be an m2eclipse bug.

Answer (score 1):

> I get suddenly an error message, that 3 dependencies are missing: gwt-user.jar, gwt-dev.jar and gxt.jar. All jars are in my local repo:

Where? On the command line? In your IDE? If this is happening in your IDE and if you are using Eclipse and the m2eclipse plugin, I've noticed that Eclipse sometimes gets lost after POM changes. In that case, **right click** on the project, then select **Maven > Update Project Configuration**. Works for me.